# bootstrap label and input size : two lines under sm size, one line over sm size with one fixed-witdh

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

is it possible in bootstrap?

I implement two-line label and input.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="example">LABEL<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
  <input id="example" class="form-control" type="text"/>
</div>
```

But I want to make these in one-line when the display width is over sm size.
So, I edit my code as follows.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="example">LABEL<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <input id="example" class="form-control" type="text"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

It looks fine except for some margin issues.
But I also want that label width size is fixed so that only input width size is flexible to right side.

Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **form-horizontal** or **form-inline** class of bootstrap

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please apply this code:

```
label {
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
#example {
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="example">LABEL<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
  <input id="example" class="form-control" type="text"/>
</div>
```

I hope it is helpful for you.

Thanks